# In opencv's findContours, what does cv.RETR_FLOODFILL do?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In the opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) it says:

> If mode equals to RETR_CCOMP or RETR_FLOODFILL, the input can also be
>   a 32-bit integer image of labels (CV_32SC1).

After sending a converted image to the function, I got 180k contours, resulting the black mess below, if I plot them. So what does `RETR_FLOODFILL` do and how do I use it correctly?

```
img = cv2.imread("lena.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image=np.array(img, dtype=np.int32),  mode=cv2.RETR_FLOODFILL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
len(contours)
Out[7]: 183295
```

[image]

Comment: Input image should be the result of connected components or flood fill functions. In your case, use Canny instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it does whatever function `cv2.floodFill` does. Finds all the pixels that are:

> 1-connected to each other
>
> 2-have intensity values close to each other

and consider them as a connected component. For example In your sample image, you have 183295 groups of pixels that are stick together and have a close intensity.